# MySQL server not working after trying to update

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I tried to update PHP 7.0 to 7.4 on Debian in Google Cloud instance, and now MySQL server is not working.

I received this message when i try to update :

```
Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
 mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
 mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Tryed to update the version of php. I was following a post that explain how to do it, so i put this commands :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and I received errors and after that MySQL is not working. I have tryed all solutions that I have found about this problem, but no one works, and don´t know what to do, please if anybody can help i will be very gratefull.

I receive this message when I try to restart MySQL server :

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

systemctl status mysql.service :

```
●mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-02-13 06:08:00 UTC; 5min ago
  Process: 8606 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 8571 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
 mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
 mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
 Stopped MySQL Community Server.
 mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
 Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
 mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
 mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is what i get with journalctl -xe :

```
Feb 13 06:26:07 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9471]: Received disconnect from 194.5.192.228 port 40696:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:07 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9471]: Disconnected from 194.5.192.228 port 40696 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:07 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9469]: Received disconnect from 81.68.143.165 port 33030:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:07 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9469]: Disconnected from 81.68.143.165 port 33030 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:09 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9463]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.185 port 39448 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:10 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9473]: Invalid user csx from 104.248.42.186 port 40838
Feb 13 06:26:10 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9473]: input_userauth_request: invalid user csx [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:10 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9473]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 13 06:26:10 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9473]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=104.248.42.186
Feb 13 06:26:12 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9463]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.185 port 39448 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:12 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9463]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 218.92.0.185 port 39448 ssh2 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:12 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9463]: Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:12 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9463]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.185  user=root
Feb 13 06:26:12 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9463]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Feb 13 06:26:13 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9473]: Failed password for invalid user csx from 104.248.42.186 port 40838 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:13 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9473]: Received disconnect from 104.248.42.186 port 40838:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:13 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9473]: Disconnected from 104.248.42.186 port 40838 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:16 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9475]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.185  user=root
Feb 13 06:26:18 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9475]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.185 port 11686 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:20 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9475]: Received disconnect from 218.92.0.185 port 11686:11:  [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:20 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9475]: Disconnected from 218.92.0.185 port 11686 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:24 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9477]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=221.131.165.85  user=root
Feb 13 06:26:27 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9477]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 10496 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:29 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9477]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 10496 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:32 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9477]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 10496 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:32 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9477]: Received disconnect from 221.131.165.85 port 10496:11:  [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:32 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9477]: Disconnected from 221.131.165.85 port 10496 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:32 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9477]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=221.131.165.85  user=root
Feb 13 06:26:34 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9479]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=221.131.165.85  user=root
Feb 13 06:26:36 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9479]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 49207 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:38 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9481]: Invalid user sudo1 from 139.210.98.218 port 58261
Feb 13 06:26:38 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9481]: input_userauth_request: invalid user sudo1 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:38 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9481]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 13 06:26:38 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9481]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=139.210.98.218
Feb 13 06:26:39 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9479]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 49207 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:39 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9481]: Failed password for invalid user sudo1 from 139.210.98.218 port 58261 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:40 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9481]: Received disconnect from 139.210.98.218 port 58261:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:40 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9481]: Disconnected from 139.210.98.218 port 58261 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:42 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9479]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 49207 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:42 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9479]: Received disconnect from 221.131.165.85 port 49207:11:  [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:42 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9479]: Disconnected from 221.131.165.85 port 49207 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:42 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9479]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=221.131.165.85  user=root
Feb 13 06:26:44 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9483]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=221.131.165.85  user=root
Feb 13 06:26:46 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9483]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 55794 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:48 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9483]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 55794 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:49 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9485]: Invalid user zsd from 61.80.179.118 port 43812
Feb 13 06:26:49 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9485]: input_userauth_request: invalid user zsd [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:49 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9485]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 13 06:26:49 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9485]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=61.80.179.118
```

It seems like there are a lot of attemps to login to the MySQL, but that is not the problem, the problem started when I Thanks

This is the version : Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch) Release: 9.13

Comment: Check MySQL's logs

Comment: Delete the same question on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66182040/8016720